# How do you align a skateboard to a landing point?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I'm making a skateboarding prototype, and like in skate 3, I'd like the player to sort of "align" gradually to their predicted landing slope. I've written the code that gets the predicted point at which the player will land, but actually rotating the player to it is proving difficult.

How can I make it so the player (by default) has their upward orientation gradually adjusted for a smooth landing, but still allow the player to spin in-air?

I've tried using LookRotation with the player's forward direction, and the predicted hit normal as the up, calculated when the player leaves the ground. This results in the player being unable to spin midair, and also tends to flip/spin out randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the predicted landing point you can find the ground inclination by casting two rays from a point above the landing point.

[image]

Having the ground inclination you can gradually lerp the inclination of the skate to match the ground inclination on landing on the Update() funcition. This way your player will still be able to control the skate and you will be always slowly adjusting the inclination.